# Problem with Piecewise function applying to matrix of polynomials

Tags: matrix, interpolation, piecewise

I have a matrix of a polynomial - function `f`

```
f[t_, i_] := wielomianSpline[t, tx[[i]], wspfi[[i]]];
```

and I want to evaluate the elements of this matrix on some consecutive intervals, so I declare `Table` from 1 to m for pairs.

```
{f[t, i], tx[[i]][[1]] <= t < tx[[i]][[2]]}

ram[t_] := Table[{f[t, i], tx[[i]][[1]] <= t < tx[[i]][[2]]}, {i, 1, m}]
```

In effect I have a piecewise function but not defined with built-in `Piecewise` because the first element from pair is a matrix, not one element. These function is not working properly.
Part of `ram[t]` is:

```
{{{2.8675 + 0.297339 t - 0.0190668 t^2 - 0.000416969 t^3, 
0.642532 + 0.349544 t - 0.0277782 t^2 + 0.000840858 t^3, 
0.964209 - 0.141672 t + 0.00272697 t^2 + 0.00194859 t^3, 
2.75501 - 0.572279 t + 0.0493086 t^2 - 0.00249783 t^3, 
5.45474 - 0.805825 t + 0.0747095 t^2 - 0.00507581 t^3}, {2.0034 + 
 0.0146207 t + 0.00504926 t^2 - 0.00145205 t^3, 
0.215403 + 0.0858344 t - 0.00519453 t^2 - 0.000170312 t^3, 
0.80491 - 0.131726 t + 0.0114366 t^2 - 0.000566484 t^3, 
2.18702 - 0.236826 t + 0.0227249 t^2 - 0.00154267 t^3, 
4.79168 - 0.44169 t + 0.0445326 t^2 - 0.00339275 t^3}, {1.52038 - 
 0.164014 t + 0.0216524 t^2 - 0.00285805 t^3, 
0.0192147 + 0.0616422 t - 0.00693677 t^2 + 0.000663834 t^3, 
0.707107 + 5.02957\[CenterDot]10^-17 t - 
 1.15177\[CenterDot]10^-18 t^2 - 6.57018\[CenterDot]10^-19 t^3, 
1.98079 - 0.0616422 t + 0.00693677 t^2 - 0.000663834 t^3, 
4.68265 - 0.19493 t + 0.0218315 t^2 - 0.00208237 t^3}, {1.32758 - 
 0.326908 t + 0.00972488 t^2 + 0.00349506 t^3, 
0.262469 + 0.236826 t - 0.0225027 t^2 + 0.00150683 t^3, 
1.19509 + 0.131726 t - 0.0114366 t^2 + 0.000566484 t^3, 
2.66489 + 0.0858344 t - 0.00551057 t^2 - 0.000119327 t^3, 
5.4675 + 0.0146207 t + 0.00423019 t^2 - 
 0.00131992 t^3}, {1.2121 + 0.118649 t - 0.0290476 t^2 + 
 0.00541545 t^3, 
0.709094 + 0.563078 t - 0.0516325 t^2 + 0.00311216 t^3, 
2.19807 + 0.416553 t - 0.036166 t^2 + 0.00179141 t^3, 
4.10663 + 0.349544 t - 0.0276011 t^2 + 0.000812286 t^3, 
7.11014 + 0.297339 t - 0.0191031 t^2 - 0.00041111 t^3}}, 0 <= t < 6.19877}, {{{3.87868 + 0.0128915 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0268209 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 
 0.000615522 (-6.19877 + t)^3,1.94218 + 0.102092 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0121413 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.000494268 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 0.654929 + 0.116758 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.0389635 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 0.00808503 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 0.507306 - 0.248909 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.00285813 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.0187623 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 2.12132 - 0.464722 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0196819 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 
 0.00428985 (-6.19877 + t)^3}, {1.94218 - 0.090165 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0219535 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.00243601 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 0.507306 + 0.00180239 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0083617 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.000767938 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 0.292893 - 0.0552406 (-6.19877 + t) + 
 0.00090211 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.000226383 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 1.22474 - 0.132924 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.00596312 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.00114241 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 2.9568 - 0.280692 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0185601 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.0029643 (-6.19877 + t)^3}, {0.654929 -0.225038 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0314968 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.0175408 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 0.292893 + 0.0521664 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.00540811 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 0.000360475 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 0.707107 - 3.97208\[CenterDot]10^-17 (-6.19877 + t) - 1.33699\[CenterDot]10^-17 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 
 4.44027\[CenterDot]10^-18 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
1.70711 - 0.0521664 (-6.19877 + t) - 
 0.00540811 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.000360475 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
3.81721 - 0.164317 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0168929 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 
 0.000940686 (-6.19877 + t)^3}, {0.507306 + 
 0.196547 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.0747201 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.0117615 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
1.22474 + 0.131546 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.0055187 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.00071875 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
1.70711 + 0.0552406 (-6.19877 + t) - 
 0.00090211 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 0.000226383 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
2.9568 + 0.00376148 (-6.19877 + t) - 
 0.00772961 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 0.000165375 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
5.40629 - 0.0850878 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0203154 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 
 0.000874402 (-6.19877 + t)^3}, {2.12132 + 
 0.382793 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.0716598 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.0117301 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
2.9568 + 0.281714 (-6.19877 + t) + 0.00624218 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.00140864 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
3.81721 + 0.174687 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.00285237 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.000716225 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
5.40629 + 0.100994 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0124955 (-6.19877 + t)^2 - 
 0.000156586 (-6.19877 + t)^3, 
8.12132 + 0.0131166 (-6.19877 + t) - 0.0267483 (-6.19877 + t)^2 + 
 0.000546281 (-6.19877 + t)^3}}, 6.19877 <= t < 8.60113},{{{3.76339 - 0.105318 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0223848 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.00135581 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
2.11052 + 0.0351983 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0157035 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.00186376 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
1.0482 + 0.163983 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0193059 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.00153233 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.185969 + 0.0896743 (-8.60113 + t) + 0.138079 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.025684 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.950778 - 0.485013 (-8.60113 + t) + 0.0112354 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.0229351 (-8.60113 + t)^3}, {1.63265 - 
 0.153468 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.00439697 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.00545595 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.474025 - 0.0250772 (-8.60113 + t) - 
 0.00282711 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 0.00221864 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.16853 - 0.0469867 (-8.60113 + t) + 
 0.00253367 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 0.000145865 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.886839 - 0.141795 (-8.60113 + t) + 
 0.00227034 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 0.00106519 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
2.21645 - 0.318544 (-8.60113 + t) + 0.00280388 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.00381896 (-8.60113 + t)^3}, {0.175729 - 
 0.0726701 (-8.60113 + t) + 0.0949209 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.0112631 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.44443 + 0.0719096 (-8.60113 + t) + 
 0.00281014 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 0.000514021 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
0.707107 - 2.70806\[CenterDot]10^-17 (-8.60113 + t) + 
 1.86315\[CenterDot]10^-17 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 2.96761\[CenterDot]10^-18 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
1.55557 - 0.0719096 (-8.60113 + t) - 
 0.00281014 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 0.000514021 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
3.33801 - 0.229196 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0101133 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.00250647 (-8.60113 + t)^3}, {1.24765 + 
 0.351917 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0100462 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.000598501 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
1.56265 + 0.145618 (-8.60113 + t) + 
 0.000338608 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 0.000808199 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
1.83147 + 0.0469867 (-8.60113 + t) - 
 0.00253367 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 0.000145865 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
2.92351 - 0.0305138 (-8.60113 + t) - 
 0.00653774 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 0.000445825 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
5.09675 - 0.167558 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0140135 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.00144932 (-8.60113 + t)^3}, {3.29186 + 
 0.524002 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0128804 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.000396896 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
3.65007 + 0.287317 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.00390998 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.00139533 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
4.21048 + 0.148582 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.00801426 (-8.60113 + t)^2 - 
 0.000459768 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 
5.57462 + 0.038245 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0136241 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 
 0.000370569 (-8.60113 + t)^3, 8.00603 - 0.105943 (-8.60113 + t) - 0.0228112 (-8.60113 + t)^2 + 0.00166199 (-8.60113 + t)^3}}, 8.60113 <= t < 10.8866}}
```

I don't want True or False on the end. I understand that I might remove this very simply but is it the same scheme as in `Piecewise`?
I don't understand how to use `Piecewise` when I have many conditions and functions defined outside `Piecewise`.
Some structure like:

```
Piecewise[{wielomianSpline[t, tx[[i]], wspfi[[i]]], tx[[i]][[1]] <= t < tx[[i]][[2]]}]
Piecewise[Table[{wielomianSpline[t, tx[[i]], wspfi[[i]]], tx[[i]][[1]] <= t < tx[[i]][[2]]},{i,1,m}]]`
```

does not work.

All of these are a part of a project: interpolating only chosen frames of a simple movie and constructing an interpolating spline on intervals, in which values are frames and the parameter is time.